# как сделать , что бы появлялся шлейф из звездочек при движении курсора как на вашем сайте

Tags: javascript

зарегистрироваться почему то, не получается пришло письмо на почту, нажимаю подтвердить, переходит по ссылке а там(Bad request) в общем поделитесь пожалуйста скриптом, который оставляет шлейф звездочек когда двигаешь мышью, как у вас на сайте, прочесал интернет вдоль и поперек, но так и не нашел скрипт,даже не знаю как это называется, буду очень благодарен , если поделитесь

Comment: А причём здесь регистрация? Судя по профилю, вы зарегестрированы.

Comment: в исходном коде SO даже любезно ссылочку на скрипт оставили=) - https://github.com/tholman/cursor-effects

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вообще ничего не понял

Comment: @Air , что тут непонятного, кликни сверху на часики справа от аватарки, и увидишь "Just like the 90s"

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, Про часики я знаю... А при чем тут регистрация? И `почему то`  ***автор*** зарегистрировался?   А потом `не получается пришло письмо на почту, нажимаю подтвердить, переходит по ссылке а там(Bad request) в общем поделитесь пожалуйста скриптом, который оставляет шлейф звездочек когда двигаешь мышью` На ***RU_so*** Вопросы принято писать по русский, а не просто кириллицей....

Comment: @Air , ну да, про регистрацию он че-то намудрил, я и сам не понял - зачем он это написал?

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery Stars cursor animation** называется я нашел. Переходишь на https://laboratory.justcoded.com/jstars/ скачиваешь . Распаковываешь архив, там должен быть скрипт этих звездочек и картинки. Чтобы все работало надо в твой файл html добавить ссылку jquery и на их скрипт. Потом в твоем документе html создать javascript с инициализацией этого плагина.

```
jQuery('#selector').jstars({
    image_path: 'images', // folder with magic image
    style: 'white',       // optional, color, default: white
    frequency: 12         // optional, from 1 to 19
});
```

jQuery('#selector').jstars({ - вот эта строчка в ней отредактировать div в котором будет работать плагин , т.е. если  то jQuery('#AAA').jstars({

А вот еще пример полюбоваться [Stars following mouse](https://codepen.io/davidhartley/pen/ByBPoq)